# How to extract labelled masks in PNG format correctly from an array?

Tags: python, image-processing, mask, scikit-image, nifti

I have the following [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XBOzV2ucC6mtGFPWjQ5p4oWjPDBzXjj_/view?usp=sharing) in `Nifti` format, which contains the masks, I have written the following code to extract the images inside as `PNG` images, the problem is that:

This is a multiclass masks labelled with [0. 1. 2. 3.], after saving the mask as `PNG` the values inside mask image are distributed among the range [0 --> 255] and they are not just 4 labels as before!

How can I solve this issue please?

**The only important thing is to have 4 unique labels inside**.

Thanks in Advance.

```
import nibabel as nib
import os
import glob
import numpy as np
from skimage.io import imread, imsave
#-------------------------------------------
# Multi Class Masks
path = 'Masks'
Dataset = glob.glob( os.path.join(path, '*.gz') )
ctr = 0
for image in Dataset:
    # Load masks voxel
    images = nib.load(image).get_fdata()
    print(np.unique(images))
    # Save it as PNG
    ctr+=1
    if(not os.path.exists('Dataset/masks/Case_'+str(ctr))):
        os.mkdir('Dataset/masks/Case_'+str(ctr))
    for _id in range(images.shape[2]):
        imsave(os.path.join('Dataset/masks','Case_'+
            str(ctr),str(ctr)+'_'+str(_id+1)+'.png'),
             resize(images[:,:,_id],(256,256)))
#-------------------------------------------
        imag = imread(os.path.join('Dataset/masks','Case_'+
             str(ctr),str(ctr)+'_'+str(_id+1)+'.png'))
        print(np.unique(imag))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to warn you, I know nothing about Nifti data and may be completely wrong here... but, I think the problem is that when you do:

```
fdata = nib.load(image).get_fdata()
```

you actually get a `float64` datatype:

```
print(fdata.dtype)
```

and PNG format only handles `uint8` or `uint16`, but not `float64`.

I assume that, as the shape of `data` is (630, 630, 45), it means there are 45 slices of something, each 630x630 - but again, I may be wrong. So, I took a fairly central slice on the basis that there is more likely to be something in the middle and I **converted it to `uint8`** and saved it as a PNG.

```
imsave('result.png', fdata[...,22].astype(np.uint8))
```

The PNG is low contrast, because all values are less than 4 on a scale of 0..255, so I increased the contrast with **ImageMagick** just so you can see it:

```
magick result.png -auto-level visible.png
```

[image]

You can get a histogram and see the frequency of occurrence of each of the 4 class labels with **ImageMagick** in Terminal:

```
magick result.png -format "%c" histogram:info
```

**Sample Output**

```
335942: (0,0,0) #000000 gray(0)      <--- there are 335,942 pixels=0
 26367: (1,1,1) #010101 gray(1)      <--- there are  26,367 pixels=1
 29419: (2,2,2) #020202 gray(2)
  5172: (3,3,3) #030303 gray(3)
```